# I am not able to click menu list option in Selenium.

Tags: selenium, geckodriver, selenium-iedriver

I have a menu which is implemented as dropdown(similarly as Flipkart menu implementation), which has some options and on mouse hover or click on each option it will again show some lists available. 
I am not able to click on menu option, I have used Action class, javascript and normal Selenium click method. However it is working in chrome browser, but in Firefox it is not working.
Please suggest if you have any solution for this.

Comment: Could you please share geckodriver version and firefox browser version?

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML and your code trials.